# Customer not receiving the place order and form submission mail with details (Magento)

Tags: magento, email

I'm trying to configure email in my magento website. My website is https://tumree.com. I just enabled contacts in system->configuration.

Send Emails To : admin@tumree.com and Email Sender: Custom Email 2.

In store email adress, In Custom email 2, sender name: Tumree admin and sender email:admin@tumree.com

When I'm trying to fill out the forms and submit, the msg "Form is submitted successfully". The account admin@tumree.com receives the email with customer name,email,number,comment.

But the customer who is filled out the form with name,email etc., not receiving the mail.

I enabled in the mail settings for return-path-> yes. But I dint reflect anything. when the order is placed, the customer not receiving the mail too with order details. Pls help me here....enter link description here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

To send emails out of your server, you probably need to do it with smtp . Your server sends  emails ("Form is submitted successfully")but they are rejected from the target server. Try it with https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html or something related.

Comment: Hi.. Yeah will try to install the above extension.. I have tried another SMTP plugin in which the form was unable to send.

Comment: After I installed the above plugin, the mail could't send and shows "Unable to submit your request".

Comment: The below lines are the error which I used for test email


SMTP Pro Self Test Results

Sending test email to your contact form address: admin@tumree.com from: tumreecom@gmail.com. Unable to send test email.

Exception message was: Could not open socket

Please check the user guide for frequent error messages and their solutions.

Default templates exist.

Email communications are enabled.

Testing failed, please review the reported problems and if you need further help visit the support page or contact me via support@aschroder.com for support.

Comment: Googling a bit I found this: https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension/issues/143